# Linear KDV eq. asymptotics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, fourier-transform, differential-equations, asymptotics

The question arises from the book Solitons by P. G. Drazin about the linearized KDV eq. 
$$
    u_t+u_{xxx}=0
$$
My first step was to take a Fourier transform of the equation, find that the dispersion relation was $-k^3$ and then to have a Fourier expansion of the form
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(kx+k^3t)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iky}dydk $$
then by playing around with $k=\alpha/(3t)^{1/3}$ I get the following terms

\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{1/3}}dy\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\alpha\frac{x-y}{(3t)^{1/3}}+\frac{\alpha^3}{3})}d\alpha\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{1/3}}\Bigg[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\alpha\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}+\frac{\alpha^3}{3})}d\alpha-\frac{y}{(3t)^{1/3}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\alpha e^{i(\alpha\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}+\frac{\alpha^3}{3})}d\alpha\Bigg]dy+\dots
\end{align}
where, to arrive at the second expression, we need to use taylor expansion for $exp(-iky)$.
Now, I'm trying to find an asymptotic expansion in the area $x/t^{1/3}\approx O(1)$, for $x>0$ and $x<0$ separately...
Drazin's book states that $x<0$ should be "a slowly decaying wave train" and $0<x$ should be "a steeply rising wave front" 
But i don't know how to arrive at that.

Could anyone lend a hand with the task?

### edit:

After awhile trying to find the asymptotics using the asymptotics or $Ai(x)$ I've come to the conclusion that it is not the way since they are based on $\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}\to\infty$ and are so useless to my effort. 
thus focusing on
\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{1/3}}dy\cdot Ai(\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}})-\int_{-\infty}^\infty y\frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{2/3}}dy\cdot Ai'(\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}})+\dots
\end{align}
I've decided to look for the asymptotics for fixed $v=\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}=o(1)$
which leads to: 
\begin{align}
u(v(3t)^{1/3},t)&=\frac{v}{x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_0(y)dy\cdot Ai(v)-\frac{v^2}{x^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y\cdot u_0(y)dy\cdot Ai'(v)+\dots
\end{align}

does anyone have an idea how to continue?

Comment: I wrote out your (long!) equations for you in TeX this time; please do it yourself the next time 'round.

Comment: @Danu, Pro top: when you have fractions in exponents either write the fractions in line with $/$ or just use $\exp$.

Comment: @Danu Thank you!! I actually had them written out in codecogs i just didn't know how to add them inline

Comment: Look for similarity solutions to the equation, then relate the ODE to Airy's equation, and the result follows. See $\S$ 13.6 in Whitham, Linear and Nonlinear Waves.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for your remark, I have done something very similar (no pun intended) in looking for a solution 
\begin{align} u(x,t) &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{1/3}}\Bigg[Ai(\frac{x}{(3t)^\frac{1}{3}})-\frac{y}{(3t)^{1/3‌​}}Ai'(\frac{x}{(3t)^\frac{1}{3}})\Bigg]dy+\dots \end{align}
which gives the intuition that the solution resembles Ai (meaning oscilatory for x<0 and steep solitaries for x>0)
but is not so simple to indeed approximate furthur (via steepest decent or stationary phase)
I'll look over Whitham again, thanks :)

Comment: In the first integral the argument $kx+k^3t$ has a unit mismatch. Do you know what happened there?

Comment: I'm actually quite certin there isn't a unit mismatch, could you explain what it is that bothers you?

Comment: @E.Shin: exponential's argument must be unitless, so for $kx$ to have not units then $[k]=1/{\rm m}$ which would force the units of $k^3t$ to be $\rm s/m^3$. Similar thing happens when you start with $[k^3t]=1$. Unless there's a "hidden" variable there (e.g., $\alpha k^3t$ with $\alpha=1$ & appropriate units), it appears that $kx+k^3t$ is a nonsensical argument for the exponential.

Comment: I suppose that is the case, if you look at the dispersion relation and you start from the physical derivation you see that there could be
$ikx-iwt=ikx-i(\gamma \cdot k^3)t$
where $\gamma$ has units $[m^3/sec]$

Comment: @Kyle Kanos On second thought that isn't the explanation, this is just the dimensionless kdv eq, there isn't a need for this sort of explanation, x and t just aren't what they usually mean.

Comment: @NickP I looked over Whitham 13.6 it's interesting but I don't find it satisfactory, the equation discussed is different, though the dispersion relation also recovers kdv, and the asymptotics is disscused for fixed $c=x/t$ and not for fixed $c=\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}$,
as well as it being discussed for $\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}\to \infty$ and not for $\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}\approx O(1)$
do you maybe have an idea where I might find a discussion in that range?

Comment: @E.Shin You should write out the entire problem as it appears in Drazin's book, as it differs from what you have written in some (crucial?) ways and makes the problem more transparent.

Comment: @NickP the linear kdv i.c. problem is given:
$u_t+u_{xxx}=0,$

$u(x,0)=u_0(x),$

$\lim{x\to+-\infty}{u_0(x)}=0$

find the asymptotics of the solution for large time $t>>1,|x|=O(t^{-1/3})$
in the cases:
a. x>0 b. x<0

Comment: while in Drazin's book it is stated:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/oKyH8.jpg
which i don't see as substatinally different.